# Add multiple query params with the same key with next/router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, query-string, next-router

I'm filtering results from an API utilizing query parameters in my Next.js app. I want to use `useRouter()` to push multiple different filters with the same key, so my query params could look like:

```
?page=1&skill=html&skill=css&skill=js
```

And I can pass each of those parameters to my API request. Right now, when I'm trying to add a skill parameter I'm using `router.push` to do it, like this:

```
const router = useRouter();

const addFilter = (skill: string) => router.push({ query: { ...router.query, skill: skill.toLowerCase() } });
```

But obviously it's overwriting the previous skill, so I'm only ever getting one of them in the URL. How can I go about adding additional query parameters with the same key, preferably using `useRouter()` or `next/router`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manipulate the query params in the URL in Next.js I use a custom hook that uses what useRouter offers, but I also add some util methods, in this case, to add a filter to the URL I have the method **addParam**.

This is the body of the custom hook.

```js
const useRouterFilter = () =>{
  const { pathname, query, push } = useRouter()

  return {
    addParam,
    ...
  }
}
```

And this would be the addFilter method inside the hook:

```js
  /**
   * Adds a query param to the URL string. Multiple params with the same name
   * and different values can be added.
   * @param name The name of the param.
   * @param value The value of the param.
   */
  const addParam = (name: string, value: string | boolean | number) => {
    const { [name]: param, ...rest } = query
    let newQuery

    if (!param) {
      newQuery = { ...rest, [name]: encodeURIComponent(value) }
    } else if (Array.isArray(param)) {
      if (param.indexOf(encodeURIComponent(value)) > -1) return
      newQuery = { ...rest, [name]: [...param, encodeURIComponent(value)] }
    } else {
      if (param === encodeURIComponent(value)) return
      newQuery = { ...rest, [name]: [param, encodeURIComponent(value)] }
    }

    push(
      {
        pathname,
        query: newQuery,
      },
      undefined,
      { shallow: true }
    )
  }
```

In this case I use `push` to add the parameters to the URL, but `replace` could also be used.

The full hook can be copied from the [following Gist](https://gist.github.com/ramirezsandin/cc93f6a405ff818e48038e28a26a1ba0)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of sending a single value you can add the skills to an array first. And then use join() to separate the values by a separator.
Ex:

```
query: { skills: skills.join(",") }
```

And of course you need to explode it again on the other side..

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `addFilter` function to add the desired `skill` value to the `skill` query parameter as an array. Making sure to deduplicate the array items, to avoid having repeated filters in the URL.

```js
const convertQueryParamToArray = (queryParam: string) => !queryParam ? [] : [queryParam];

const addFilter = async (skill: string) => {
    // Force `skill` query param into an array
    const currentSkillArray = Array.isArray(router.query.skill)
        ? router.query.skill
        : convertQueryParamToArray(router.query.skill);
    // Deduplicate skills with same value
    const newSkillArray = [...new Set([...currentSkill, skill.toLowerCase()])];
    router.push({
        query: { ...router.query, skill: newSkillArray }
    });
};
```

Given the above function and assuming your URL starts as `/?page=1`, calling `addFilter('html')` would make the URL become `/?page=1&skill=html`. A following call to `addFilter('css')` would update the URL to `/?page=1&skill=html&skill=css`. And so on.